# SSH/Shell - Remove all folders with name "____" within folder AND subfolders

Tags: shell, ssh

I have a script that is copying a folder that contains a couple sub folders. The original that it is copying from is part of an SVN folder, so it is copying those ".svn" folders as well.

I want to remove those from the new destination, my best guess was:

```
rm -Rf dir/*.svn
```

Which doesn't work, is there a way to do this or do I need to manually go into each folder to delete it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From within the folder whose contents you want to filter:

`find . -name '.svn' -print0 | xargs -0 rm -rf`

or

`find . -name '.svn' -exec rm -rf {} \;`

Comment: (The `-print0`/`-0` combo is in case your paths have any whitespace in them.)

Comment: If I wanted that to also be another directory (such as DW's _notes) would that be a separate command or could that get added into this one?

Comment: `find . -name '.svn' -o -name '_notes' -print0 | xargs -0 rm -rf`

Name is .svn OR name is _notes

Comment: You could also do it with one of the regex flags, but Stephen's answer (+1'd) is easier (particularly if you're not awesome with regexes).

Comment: You could also avoid copying the .svn directories in the first place, so they don't have to be removed. Check `man rsync` and the `--exclude=` option. (Note rsync can be used for local-to-local copies, it doesn't *have* to be remote)

Comment: I know regex pretty well, but have no idea how to use in shell (don't know any of the flags)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this: http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/2486